# How to reduce battery usage of app?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, battery-saver

I am developing an app which tracks the user location for every 10-20 secs. In order to make it work in the background and mobile locked stage, I had to make the following code edits:

In Android:

I added permission of "Wake_Lock" and added a line of code in MainActivity.cs like

```
this.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn, WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
```

In iOS (AppDelegate.cs):

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = true;
```

This makes the functionality good and it is tracking the location for every 10 secs even in background and mobile is locked which is good. But by adding this code the battery usage by the app is increased drastically.

Can anyone please help me if I am doing anything wrong and suggest me any idea to get the battery usage problem solved.

Comment: Hi stedy.Can you please suggest a solution for my problem

Comment: You need to prevent screen lock or can let the app run during screen is locked?

Comment: Yes Janson I did the same to run the code in background.But the app is draining the battery.So please suggest any ideas to reduce the battery usage along with working my functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = true;" to prevent the phone goes into sleep mode, could you try to use the "Background Location"?

You can take a look in [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/BackgroundLocationDemo/) Demo app.

Comment: Thanks Janson.It works for iOS but what can i do for Android?

Comment: Please note that it is a "Xamarin" solution not "Xamarin.Forms". It included the demo code for both iOS and Android platform.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Janson I am doing a cross platform xamarin.forms app

Comment: Unfortunately, not everything can be abstracted,so Xamarin.Forms has it limitation.Below URL is a reference for Xamarin.Forms backgrounding (http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/), you can have a look and try to implement the location service with it.Hope it could help